# Как получить в админке данные через обратную связь при использовании GenericTabularInline?

Tags: django, django-admin

Я могу добавить "критерии" какому то "месту". Как добавить "места" какому то "критерию"?

Модели:

```
class Criterias(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Places(models.Model):
    name = ...

class PlacesToCriterias(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    criteria_group = models.ForeignKey(Criterias)
```

Админка - Места:

```
class PlaceCriteriasInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class PlacesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PlaceCriteriasInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Places, PlacesAdmin)
```

В данном случае, на странице редактирования "Места" я могу добавить "Критерии".

Админка - Критерии:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(GenericTabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

В данном случае, на странице редактирования "Критерия" я НЕ могу добавить "Места". Вместо возможного списка мест я вижу список критериев.

Как получить список мест на странице критерия?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто - нужно было вместо `GenericTabularInline` использовать `admin.TabularInline`

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

Если кому-то нужно вывести это все красиво - вместо полей `content_type` и `object_id` вывести объект напрямую, вам [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578248/183146).