# Как заменить в inline в админке поля content_type и object_id на выпадающий список с выбранным объектом?

Tags: django, django-admin

У меня есть `inline`, который отображает `contenttype` модель, таким образом выводятся поля `content_type` и `object_id`. Я могу их скрыть используя `exclude`, но мне так же нужно вывести выпадающий список со всеми "Местами" и выбранным текущим местом на основе `content_type` и `object_id`. Как мне это сделать?

Модели:

```
class Criterias(models.Model):
    name = ...

class Places(models.Model):
    name = ...

class PlacesToCriterias(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    criteria_group = models.ForeignKey(Criterias)
```

Админка:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

Я могу добавить форму к inline `CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin`:

```
class CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    places = forms.ModelChoiceField(PlaceTypesGroups.objects.all(), label='place')
```

но как в данном случае передать `content_type` и `object_id` в эту форму, чтоб получить выпадающий список со всеми "Местами" и с выбранным текущим местом на основе `content_type` и `object_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.

Добавить форму в `admin.TabularInline`:

```
class CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PlacesToCriterias
    form = CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm  # <- ADDED FORM

class CriteriasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CriteriaPlacesInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(Criterias, CriteriasAdmin)
```

Сама форма:

```
class CriteriaPlacesChoicesFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ct_place_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(PlaceTypesGroups)

    object_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(PlaceTypesGroups.objects.all(), label='places')
    content_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(ContentType.objects.all(), initial=ct_place_type, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean_object_id(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['object_id'].pk

    def clean_content_type(self):
        return self.ct_place_type
```